# Recycle and reload application pool on IIS7

Tags: asp.net, iis, dynamics-ax-2009

Is there a way to recycle and afterwards reload an application pool?

My problem has been slow performance when logging in to my web application. I found out that the "Idle Time-out(minutes)" was sat to 20 by default. This caused the application to terminate when idle so that it can start up again on the next visit. After searching the web i found out that this value could be sat to 0 so it won't terminate. However, the first visit after recycling, an app pool have to create a new w3wp.exe worker process which is slow because the app pool needs to be created, ASP.NET or another framework needs to be loaded, and then the application needs to be loaded. [Source right here](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2013/04/06/why-is-the-iis-default-app-pool-recycle-set-to-1740-minutes.aspx)

This means that every time the app recycles, the first visitor have to wait longer then the other visitors when logging in, doing some stuff and log out.

The web application is using the ISS from Dynamics AX 2009.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Sorry I thought you are working on IIS 7.5
But there was a beta for this in IIS7 actually.*

I think you are looking something along the lines of this

A warmup module for IIS 7.5

*"IIS Application Initialization for IIS 7.5 enables website administrators to improve the responsiveness of their Web sites by loading the Web applications before the first request arrives. By proactively loading and initializing all the dependencies such as database connections, compilation of ASP.NET code, and loading of modules, IT Professionals can ensure their Web sites are responsive at all times even if their Web sites use a custom request pipeline or if the Application Pool is recycled. While an application is being initialized, IIS can also be configured to return an alternate response such as static content as a placeholder or "splash page" until an application has completed its initialization tasks."*

Download Link
http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-initialization

And also have a look at this; which  basically talks about using warm up classes which comes with ASPNET 4

http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/01/31/asp-net-4-0-how-to-use-application-warm-up-class.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the suspend option.

IIS now has

`Idle Time-out Action : Suspend` setting

Suspending is just freezes the process and it is much more efficient than the destroying the process. Because it uses the same process and does not create another one after waking up.